# Laravel Model whereOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel

I am aware of the use of Model::firstOrCreate, updateOrCreate how do I create a model instance when a condition is not met. Something like this:

```js
Model::where('number', $num)->orCreate(['number' => $num, 'another' => $another]);
```

I am trying to store information through an excel file to a table, one of the field is however unique, how can I handle this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what `firstOrCreate()` can be used for.

```
Model::firstOrCreate(
    ['number' => $num],
    ['another' => $another]
);
```

would find a Model where `['number' => $num]`, if it doesn't find one, it will create a new Model with `['number' => $num]` *and* `['another' => $another]`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods